# how to use a custom subclass of the spring-boot JarLauncher?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

i have a situation where one of my required dependency jars also has an older version of a dependency embedded in it (uber-jar style).

sadly, the embedded dependency is incompatible with some other dependencies.

i figured out a strategy using a custom version of `com.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` where i can manipulate the order of jar files in the classpath by overriding the `postProcessClassPathArchives` method.

this strategy is based on [this blog post on the topic](http://dkublik.github.io/spring-boot-class-loader-and-class-override/), but in my case, instead of making sure that the `classes` folder appears first in the classpath, i am pushing a compatible version of the incompatible embedded classes first.

the referenced blog post places the subclass of `JarLauncher` in the project itself, but in my case, this situation would occur in multiple projects, so i want to factor out the custom subclass of `JarLauncher` into it's own project and make it available as a distinct dependency via some appropriate maven repository.

the blog post also uses gradle `copySpec` to copy the custom launcher class from `${buildDir}/classes` into the root of the spring-boot jar so that it is accessible by the class-loader responsible for loading the class called out as a `Main-Class` in the manifest.

so, my question is around options for achieving a similar result, but using a custom launcher embedded in a dependency jar.

i'm wondering if i can reference the custom launcher from within a jar file placed at the root of the boot-jar, or if i need to extract the contents and just move the discrete class there.

either way, i'm only familiar with gradle basics, and not sure how to accomplish either of those options via gradle techniques.

any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

after some research and tinkering i came up with the following solution:

```
configurations {
  bootHelpr { transitive = false }
}

dependencies {
  //...
  bootHelpr 'com.github.the-watchmen:boot-helpr:1.0.0'
}

bootJar {
  with copySpec {
    from(zipTree(configurations.bootHelpr.singleFile))
  }
}
```

where `boot-helpr` is the dependency containing the custom `JarLauncher`...

i consider myself a gradle hack, so feel free to post any more idiomatic solutions ;)